# Removing Dynamic JQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating a web application and I want to use the Tabs widget to replicate the tab functionality you find in most web browsers. I want the user to be able: to move (sort) the tabs around, create tabs dynamically, close tabs dynamically.

I am having a problem deleting tabs that have been moved around.

Lets say there are three tabs named:

> one, two and three.

If I move "one" so the tabs are like:

> two, three and one

When I delete "one", which has an index of 2, tab "three" is deleted. So the tabs are now:

> two, and one.

I have tested many different scenarios and it appears to me when I remove a tab, JQueryUI removes the wrong tab that initially had the index value, and not the tab that currently has the index value.

Comment: I have no idea why jQuery UI doesn't use IDs for the tab as well as indexes, this way has led to a whole slew of headaches for us as well.

Comment: $(`#tab_ID`).tabs("refresh"); this worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right that the tabs keep their old index values when you reorder them, leading to unexpected behavior when you try to remove one. You can force it to update the indexes by reinitializing the tabs before deleting, like so:

```
$('#tabs').tabs('destroy').tabs();
$('#tabs').tabs('remove', 2);
```

This works because the indexes are generated when the tabs are set up based on the positions of the `li` elements in the DOM. When you move the tabs around, the `li` positions are updated in the DOM, even if their index values don't change in the Tabs plugin.

Of course, if you have a very complicated setup, this might have negative performance implications, in which case you could figure out some other way to update the tab indexes, or you could maintain an array that maps the original indexes to the current indexes.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to "refresh" the indexes. Thank you.

Comment: This technique is actually causing me a bug now - When I create new tabs at runtime, the destroy method removes all runtime tabs as well as the intended tab.

Comment: yeah same here. it removes everything.

Comment: I found that you can pass the href of the intended tab instead of an index and it'll translate it to the "correct" index based on the internal ones kept by the tabs. This was using jQuery ui 1.8.11, I haven't tested it with any other version

Answer (score 4):

Annoyingly *remove* is no longer in the [jQueryUI tab API](https://blog.jqueryui.com/2011/03/tabs-api-redesign/). You must now remove the HTML that renders the tab and panel itself and refresh the tabs:

```
function removeTab(tabId) {
  var tabIdStr = "#tabs-" + tabId

  // Remove the panel
  $( tabIdStr ).remove();
  // Refresh the tabs widget
  tabs.tabs( "refresh" );

  // Remove the tab
  var hrefStr = "a[href='" + tabIdStr + "']"
  $( hrefStr ).closest("li").remove()
}
```

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/dynamically-remove-tab

Answer (score 1):

I temporarily solved the problem this way:

```
.click(function(e) {
$tab.tabs('remove',$tab.tabs('option','selected'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated in June 2023

The below function started using Matthew's answer above.

I modified it for more flexibility as some of us will have different #IDs for our elements.

```
function removeTab(tabsObj,tabId) {
    let returnVal = false;
    if($(tabId).length && $( tabId ).remove()){
        $(tabsObj).tabs( "refresh" );
        let hrefStr = "a[href='" + tabId + "']"
        if($( hrefStr ).closest("li").remove()){
            returnVal = true;
        }
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

It also returns a false if the tab doesn't exist and true on success